# How come address value stored in an array is same as its own address, it should be pointing to some different address (&arr[0])?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int arr[3]{0,1,2};
cout<<"The value of arr "<<arr<<'\n'; 
cout<<"The address of &arr "<<&arr<<'\n';
cout<<"The address of &arr[0] "<<&arr[0]<<'\n';
cout<<"The value in arr[0] "<<arr[0]<<'\n';
}

OUTPUT

The value of arr 0x7ffd1a658e74
The address of &arr 0x7ffd1a658e74
The address of &arr[0] 0x7ffd1a658e74
The value in arr[0] 0
```

Here address value in array *arr* is same as *&arr*, since array is a pointer pointing to its first element so value *arr* should be equal equal to *&arr[0]* which is found equal to *&arr*. So how come *arr* can have two values: address value of *&arr[0]* and value at *arr[0]*, since *arr = &arr[0] = &arr*

Comment: You've just discovered C++'s dirty little secret. All arrays are a figment of your imagination. Or a nightmare (take your pick). They are a mirage. They do not exist. And since they don't exist, they can't possibly have an address that belongs just to them, and to nothing else, see?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik But as per the above, array is pointing to itself, arr and &arr are same.

Comment: The value of `&arr` and `&arr[0]` are the same, since the first element of an array occupies a cell of memory at the start of `arr`.  Their types are different.   Try to calculate the expression `&arr == &arr[0]` (for example, `bool same = (&arr == &arr[0])` in order to print the value, and you will find the code will not compile due to the types differing.

Comment: @Peter Since &arr and &arr[0] are equal, which means value in &arr[0] is lying in &arr, Now array is also a pointer that means it has an address value to its first location, so that means arr has two has values one address of &arr[0] and its value arr[0]. How is that possible ?

Comment: Yes. `arr` and `&arr` are the same. A pointer to a mirage, a figment of your imagination, is also a mirage, and a figment of your imagination.

Comment: @user10867746  -   You've made a common beginner misinterpretation.   An array is not a pointer, and a pointer is not an array.   Although the name of an array can be converted to a pointer (to its first element) in some circumstances, that conversion does not mean an array is a pointer or vice versa.   Your problem is that you are reasoning about them as if they are the same thing - because the answer to your question hinges on the fact they are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break this down:

- `arr` is evaluated as a pointer to its first element. So it returns the address of the first element of the array.
- `&arr` is the 'address of the array', which is evaluated to the address of its first element. I think you were stuck up on this one, since `arr` itself is evaluated as a pointer to the first element, and thus it should be the 'address of the address of the first element'. But in this case, the array is not first evaluated to a pointer to the first element, it just returns the address of it as-is.
- `&arr[0]` is accessing the first element of `arr`, and then retrieving the address of that.

Thus, all three of these will return the address of the first element.

Edit: One thing that should be noted is the type mismatch between `&arr` and `&arr[0]`. The former will be refer to an array type, while the latter will refer to the element type. Doing arithmetic operations with them will lead to wildly different results.

Comment: All three of these return same value, i.e., &arr == arr == &arr[0], which means &arr[0] lies in &arr, Now arr is also a pointer so &arr will have two values one &arr[0] and arr[0]. How is that possible ?

Comment: @user10867746 '... which means `&arr[0]` lies in &arr`': no it doesn't.

Comment: @user10867746 The difference being, `&arr[0]` is taking the **first element** of the array, and returning its address, while `&arr` is returning the address of the **array itself**, which is the same as the address of the first element. Also, `arr` is only implicitly converted to a pointer to the first element when it is evaluated by itself. When it is combined with  the `&` operator, this is not the case.